# What is the difference between 貸付金 and 借入金?

Tags: nuances

When I translate both of these terms, the English is approximately loan or debt or borrowing.

The first one, 貸付金{かしつけきん}, is commonly used by banks to advertise loans.  However, I have seen 借入金{かりいれきん} used on tax forms.

What is the difference?

Comment: I could find [this page](https://avacs.co.jp/kariire-dx/loan.php). For the daily usage, I don't think there's a difference (at least not more than the difference between 貸す and 借りる). If you want to know the judicial difference, unfortunately I guess it goes beyond what an average person in this platform can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the comments, the two are expressions that are opposite in meaning. This makes sense, as 借りる means to borrow and 貸す means to lend. [In the link](https://avacs.co.jp/kariire-dx/loan.php#_-8) @sams-studio provided, it explains that:

> 貸付金は資産の増加と負債の減少を意味するお金です。
> 貸付金 is money loaned, meaning this is money that adds to your capital.

This means that 貸付金 is a loan *from the loaner's perspective*. Essentially, this is money that your or your company has loaned to another party. In contrast, [借入金 means](https://avacs.co.jp/kariire-dx/loan.php#_-9):

> 借入金は資産の減少と負債の増加を意味するお金です。
> 借入金 is money borrowed that essentially means a decrease in your capital.

It is essentially a loan an outside party makes to a you. This is money that you or your company has borrowed, and must return to the lender. Both words mean loan (money), but from the perspectives of different parties. 貸付金 from the lender's perspective, and 借入金 from the borrower's perspective. To simplify this explanation, [this site](https://manekai.ameba.jp/cardloan/loan/#:%7E:text=%E5%80%9F%E5%85%A5%E9%87%91%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%80%81%E8%B2%B8%E4%BB%98%E9%87%91,%E5%80%9F%E5%85%A5%E9%87%91%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AB%E5%88%86%E9%A1%9E%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82) says:

> 借入金とは、貸付金とは反対の意味を持つ言葉です。貸付金は貸したお金を意味しますが、借入金は借りるお金を意味します。
> 借入金 and 貸付金 are words that hold opposite meanings. 貸付金 is money lended, while 借入金 means money borrowed.

The definitions of [貸付金](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%B2%B8%E4%BB%98%E9%87%91-462105) and [借入金](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%80%9F%E5%85%A5%E9%87%91-47346) on Kotobank essentially say the same thing.

Comment: I didn't think to find the verb form from the nouns.  Your first paragraph is very helpful!